# Secure webapp with Django and React

Tags: reactjs, django, security, authentication, backend

I'm experimenting with these 2 technologies to make a secure web app [Currently learning React (60%) and Django (<50%). This is intended to be like a medical database, so doctors and nurses enters their patients' information. They need to login obviously. I wanted to implement React-based UI (And not using the classic method to create views from django), so I've found many tutorials just like this one:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react

It basically turns Django into a restAPI, and then the React frontend uses axios to retrieve data from the endpoint. Sounds not bad at all (comparing to the native method of rendering data in a webpage from Django), but the **problem** is that I have no idea on how to make this secure, you know, Django provides an auth system, which is pretty good and secure, I have to say, but in a project with this structure, the auth needs to be done in React, so there many questions appear:

- **To start with, is it a good idea to make a project of this structure?** (If no, then what could be a good one)
- If it's a yes, **how can I protect the API so only logged in users can interact with it?** (What mechanisms to ensure protection)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely a good idea to separate the client application and the backend server application.

- You can access the backend through the rest api basically with any frontend framework/app/script.
- Customers are able to extend their own applications with the abilities of your backend service.
- You can create multiple different frontends that use the same backend or different parts of the same backend via the rest api (multi-branding, reselling). Or you can just swap the frontend framework every second year to a new one.
- It's also easier to create different automations by using the rest api.

And the list goes on.

For django rest api auth I would recommend [Token Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) which is already included in the Django REST Framework and for React use [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications) tutorial for implementing the login and the token handling.

And don't forget to use TLS on your servers, and create API documentation. [(Example)](https://stripe.com/docs/api)

Comment: tysm, I have a couple questions tho.. `any way to contact with you outside this thread? :D`